# Update new column with data after checking through unique value of another column

Tags: sql

I have a data set similar to this

```
ID  Class
11111   A
11111   C
11111   B
22222   B
22222   C
33333   A
33333   D
33333   C
33333   B
44444   A
```

Here, i require to add another column "Final Class" which would compare the classes between the same ID and give a unique output. For example, for 11111 i would want all the three rows in the column "Final Class" to say A. Here the comparison being A vs B vs C take A. where as for 22222 I would like it to say B.

```
ID  Class   Final Class
111111  A   A
111111  C   A
111111  B   A
22222   B   B
22222   C   B
33333   A   A
33333   D   A
33333   C   A
33333   B   A
44444   C   C
```

The priority being set as A, B, C and D.

Can anyone help me with this?

I tried update case when but unable to figure it out

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: I reverted your edit for this reason: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Most sql systems support window functions. What is your DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested the query but it should be something like this . The min function will get the letter with the highest priority from the group by, because A<B<C<D .

```
with cte as (
    select id, min(class) as final_class from data
    group by id
    )
    select  i.id, 
            i.class, 
            cte.final_class
    from data i left join cte on i.id = cte.id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with a sub-queries. Something along these lines should work, since you didn't share the actual table schema or the database you are working with.

```
update o
from Data o
set tbl.FinalClass = (select max(cls) from Data i where i.Id = o.Id);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for helping. I was not able to use this perhaps because i have not explained it well enough. I have a table with those two column and i want to update that table itself with an additional column Final Class where the final class will take the data according to the priority set (Say min or max A,B,C,D)

Answer (score -1):

Since most DBMS support `window functions`, You can try this :

```
select ID, Class, MIN(Class) over (partition by ID) as 'Final Class'
from mytable
```

If you are using an old version, then you can use subquery to find the min Class :

```
select t.*, s.minClass as 'Final Class'
from mytable t
inner join (
  select ID, MIN(Class) as minClass
  from mytable
  group by ID
) as s on s.ID = t.ID
```

[The is a demo on mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/RHIOzVX0)